# My function for some reason auto-converts a string into a tuple?

Tags: python, string, function, tuples

I'm very confused here. I'm trying to pass an optional string parameter to my function, but once the parameter is added, it converts the string to a tuple? How can I stop it from doing that or convert back?

I have this:

```
def fen2grid(note, *optional)
    print(optional)
    # here it does other stuff
```

With this when I call it:

```
fen2grid(example, '.')
```

now... the print is supposed to print a period. Just .
This is just a test before I use it in the function and it seems to be a good thing that I'm testing it.What it prints is

('.',)

I need the period because I need to work with that (it can be any other symbol too)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

`*args` reads an arbitrary number of arguments and encloses them as a tuple. To access them you can simply do `print(args[0])` or `[print(x) for x in args]`

Edit: Keep in mind that neither args or kwargs are keywords, you can replace them for any other placeholder preceded by * or **

Comment: Thank you, this worked, I had no idea this was how it worked. It looks like a list to me and we're using the index 0. This made it clear!

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to pass an optional string parameter to my function

`*optional` isn't quite how you do that. At least not for default/keyword argument like you are trying to use. That *is a tuple*.

Try

```
def fen2grid(note, optional=None)
    print(optional)
```

For more details, see about [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions).

Comment: See the link in my update. "Default Argument Values"